# Localizing price details -- E.G. $50 Vs RMB 1000

Tags: iphone, cocoa, localization

I want to localize the price in my iPhone app. Can you please guide me how to achieve this.

For example:

$50 Vs A$ 1,480.00 Vs RMB 1450 Vs £999.00
etc.

Comment: Doesn't this change minute by minute?

Comment: I did not get you? I want to show the price in UK with £ symbol but in USA with $ symbol. Also, in some countries currency symbol is written after the amount and in some countries it is written before the amount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:price];

NSLog(@"Local price: %@", formattedString);
```

if you just want the currency symbol, you can use:

```
NSString *sym = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

1. How to convert a number in one currency to another currency, especially since currency exchange rates fluctuate hourly.
2. How to format a number in a specific currency format.

The second one is fairly simple, and @coneybeare answered it in his post: use an `NSNumberFormatter`.

The first part is also fairly simple, if you know where to look. I recommend checking out a unit converter library I wrote called DDUnitConverter: https://github.com/davedelong/DDUnitConverter

One of the conversion modules it has is a currency converter,  which asynchronously pulls it's rates from the International Monetary Fund.